# apostrophecms not loging in

Tags: node-modules, apostrophe-cms

PS C:\Users\Administrator> cd G:\ApostropheCMSprg\apos
PS G:\ApostropheCMSprg\apos> npm start

```
> a3-boilerplate@1.0.0 start
> node app

(node:6380) DeprecationWarning: isConnected is deprecated and will be removed in the next major version
(Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)
‍ Building the Public-facing modern JavaScript and Sass...
 Public-facing modern JavaScript and Sass is complete!
‍ Building the Raw CSS and JS...
 Raw CSS and JS is complete!
Watching for UI changes...
Listening at http://localhost:3000
Error: Cannot find module './utf16'
Require stack:
- G:\ApostropheCMSprg\apos\node_modules\iconv-lite\encodings\index.js
- G:\ApostropheCMSprg\apos\node_modules\iconv-lite\lib\index.js
- G:\ApostropheCMSprg\apos\node_modules\express\node_modules\raw-body\index.js
- G:\ApostropheCMSprg\apos\node_modules\express\node_modules\body-parser\lib\read.js
- G:\ApostropheCMSprg\apos\node_modules\express\node_modules\body-parser\lib\types\json.js
- G:\ApostropheCMSprg\apos\node_modules\express\node_modules\body-parser\index.js
- G:\ApostropheCMSprg\apos\node_modules\express\lib\express.js
- G:\ApostropheCMSprg\apos\node_modules\express\index.js
- G:\ApostropheCMSprg\apos\node_modules\apostrophe\modules\@apostrophecms\asset\index.js
- G:\ApostropheCMSprg\apos\node_modules\apostrophe\lib\moog-require.js
- G:\ApostropheCMSprg\apos\node_modules\apostrophe\index.js
- G:\ApostropheCMSprg\apos\app.js
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1075:15)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:920:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1141:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:110:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (G:\ApostropheCMSprg\apos\node_modules\iconv-lite\encodings\index.js:7:5)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1254:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1308:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1117:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:958:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1141:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:110:18)
    at Object.getCodec (G:\ApostropheCMSprg\apos\node_modules\iconv-lite\lib\index.js:63:27)
    at Object.getDecoder (G:\ApostropheCMSprg\apos\node_modules\iconv-lite\lib\index.js:125:23)
    at getDecoder (G:\ApostropheCMSprg\apos\node_modules\raw-body\index.js:46:18)
    at readStream (G:\ApostropheCMSprg\apos\node_modules\raw-body\index.js:194:15)
    at getRawBody (G:\ApostropheCMSprg\apos\node_modules\raw-body\index.js:116:12)
```

i tried to login to my new apostrophe project but it doesn't recoginise the admin details and give this error message

Answer (score 0):

I am one of the developers on ApostropheCMS. It looks like you are not using Windows Subsystem for Linux. [Since Microsoft recommends Windows Subsystem for Linux for Node.js work](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/dev-environment/javascript/nodejs-on-wsl#install-wsl-2), and the alternative builds of Node for Windows are not a good simulation of the results you will get when you deploy your project in a Linux environment, we have focused our documentation and testing efforts on Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL).

Please see our [Windows development environment guide](https://v3.docs.apostrophecms.org/cookbook/windows-development.html) for steps to set up WSL for ApostropheCMS.